# GitHub Action using npx fails with message /usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, github-actions, npx

I'm creating a nodejs GitHub Action that relies on npx to run semantic-release:

`src/index.ts` *(extract, bundled to `dist/index.js`)*

```js
import * as core from '@actions/core'
import * as exec from '@actions/exec'
import * as github from '@actions/github'

;(async () => {
  const githubRegistry: string = `https://npm.pkg.github.com/${github.context.repo.owner}`
  const githubToken: string = core.getInput('github_token', { required: true })

  await exec.exec('npx', ['semantic-release'], {
    NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY: githubRegistry,
    NPM_TOKEN: githubToken,
    GITHUB_TOKEN: githubToken
  })
})()
```

`action.yml` *(extract)*

```yaml
inputs:
  github_token:
    required: true
runs:
  using: node12
  main: dist/index.js
```

`.github/workflows/release.yml`

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main

jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: 12
    - run: yarn
    - uses: ./
      with:
        github_token:  ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

When the release workflow is ran on GitHub, it fails with the following output:

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/12.19.0/x64/bin/npx semantic-release
/usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/12.19.0/x64/bin/npx' failed with exit code 127
```

It looks like npx is trying to run node but could not find it.

I would appreciate any help, thanks :)

Comment: Julien, were you able to resolve this?